# enum type and struct in header file

Tags: c, enums, struct, header-files

I have a header file `buildTree.h` and a C file `buildTree.c` there is a struct typedef'd in the header file and I would like one of the struct members to be of an enum type

the header file code is:

```
#define TREE_ITEM_LIMIT 100

typedef enum pType {
    none = 0,
    bool = 1,
    number = 2,
    baud = 3    
}pType;

typedef struct tree {
    // 27 byte size struct
    char longName [13];
    char shortName [5];
    char shortParent [5];
    ptype parameterType;
    void (* handler)(int);
}tree;

extern tree item[TREE_ITEM_LIMIT];
extern tree defaultValues;
```

If i then attempt to assign a value to a the parameterType member in the C file a get a bucket-load of errors that basically say my struct is pretty screwy.
Whats really strange is that if I remove the assignment again, the errros dont go away the next time I compile! I have to remove the pType member from the struct, compile, then the errors are gone. If I add it back in again the errors stay gone until I try the assignment again...

Guessing Im not using the enum in the header correctly, but I cant see how...

EDIT: I did try commenting out the bool in the enum just in case that was playing up but no change

Comment: What errors does your compiler emit? "ZOMG it b0rken!" is not a helpful description of the problem.

Comment: maybe show some of your c-file where you create your tree

Comment: PS - if this is because you mistyped "pType" as "ptype" in your struct, the gods will punish you.

Comment: @Toby Are you using `#ifndef FILE_H_` in the begging of your header file? The errors maybe a result of multiple-definitions

Comment: @tbert It is no-problem to typedef a struct with the same name `typedef struct str { } str;`. I just have tried it in VS.

Comment: @Desolator reread what I wrote, because it isn't what you apparently read

Comment: @tbert, could you make your capitalization comment an answer, because the god(s) are currently throwing just about everything they can lay their hands on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is because you mistyped "pType" as "ptype" in your struct, the gods will punish you.

And next time, read the very first line of error output and fix that.

Comment: Well and truly sitting in the corner wearing the dunce cap :) Ta

Answer (score 1):

naming a enumeration constant `bool` is a particularly bad idea. This is reserved for "stdbool.h", and you may get plenty of problems with at. If this is what you are facing we can't say, since you gave us neither your compiler version, nor the error output.

Comment: The OP mentioned that commenting out `bool` made no difference (though you're right about using it in the first place).

Comment: yes I thought this myself however my parameter type is of boolean and I need to be able to determine the response based on the type which could also be a baud number, a regular integer, an exponential, etc... bool has obvious meaning to somebody adding new items to the tree, any suggestions to the contrary welcome. Using mingw but not sure of version, its in dev-c v4

Comment: `bool` is *almost* something like a keyword, you wouldn't want to name an enumeration constant `int`, wouldn't you. In any case your names don't give enough context, you should add that, something like `parm_none`, `parm_baud`, ...